# How to stop "Cell Info Display" in HTC Desire X Duos

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, cell-broadcast, htc-desire-x

this question is with regards to HTC Desire X dual Sim. I have this device and since the day I purchased this device I am suffering a lot with the CID massages, in a minute I am getting 10-15 messages, and I am not able to turn that off. So please suggest me how to turn the CID massages off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the SIM in another HTC mobile like Wildfire and go to `settings > call > cell broadcast > uncheck it` and delete any subscribed channels like 50.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone got problem with cell broadcast sms or service messages, just first save the channel in any name and just block that channel in message block list. If can't block in default sms application, just download any sms application from android market ( i used Handscent sms) and block the channel

Answer (score -3):

Put the sim in any Nokia handset and deactivate the cell info to stop the irritating broadcast messages.

Comment: Most people don't have other handsets just lying around.